# How can I put elements under a absolute position's element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.absolute_postion{
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  
}

.other_elements{
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="absolute_postion">foo</div>
  <div class="other_elements">bar</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, `div.other_elements` is under `div.absolute_postion`. How can I put that in the bottom of `div.absolute_postion`?

Comment: Absolute positioning is, in fact, **absolute** and doesn't depend on other elements (such as an element before it). So there's no way to do that. You might want to wrap everything inside a wrapper and set the wrapper as absolute and its children as relative

Comment: If div.other_elements has to be relative, then you could add a padding/margin-top equal to the height of div.absolute_position. Otherwise but them both in a single container, and move the position: absolute style to the container instead of div.absolute_position.

Comment: if `height` of element with absolute positioning is dynamic then there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Give `top:0` to `.absolute_postion` class and `margin-top:30px` to `.other_elements`.

```css
.absolute_postion{
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  top:0;  
}

.other_elements{
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="absolute_postion">foo</div>
  <div class="other_elements">bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You know, the `height` of `.absolute_postion` element is dynamic. So I cannot set `margin-top:30px` to `.other_elements`.

Comment: Why do you need to have the first one absolute then? Since having two simple divs achieves exactly what you want to do?

Comment: @stack for dynamic height you have to measure height with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I see the height of .absolute_postion element is dynamic so you can achieve this with jquery.
You can use `height()` method to get the pixels of the div and apply margin-top with that value:

```js
var val = $('.absolute_postion').height()
$('.other_elements').css('margin-top', val);
console.log(val)
```

```css
.absolute_postion{
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  top:0; 
}

.other_elements{
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="absolute_postion">foo</div>
  <div class="other_elements">bar</div>
</div>
```

> Note: Remember add `top:0` to absolute_postion div.

Comment: @stack Check my answer please

Answer (score 0):

Just Adding top margin equal to the height of `absolute_position` div

```css
.absolute_postion {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  top: 0;
}

.other_elements {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="absolute_postion">foo</div>
  <div class="other_elements">bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That requires you to set a fixed height though.

Comment: `padding` will affect `border` of `.other_elements` and background-color etc